# How to edit a py file from terminal?

Tags: command-line, terminal

I am working in a `VM` via `PuTTY`.

Via terminal, I want to open, edit, and save a `.py` file. How can I do it?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Simply use any command line text editor you have installed on the machine... vi, vim, nano, etc. `nano file.py`

Comment: `.py` files are text files.  You might want to broaden your question/search to text fiiles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also have to enter a command like i to get into insert mode. Then hit esc and :wq to save and quit. If you are using terminal often it may be helpful to have a [cheat sheet](https://www.maketecheasier.com/vim-keyboard-shortcuts-cheatsheet/)

Answer (score 18):

The easiest way is to use vim

```
vim your_script.py
```

Edit your file and save it using :w or :x

You can also use emacs or nano

Comment: Those are good options, in my opinion the easiest way is by using nano. Also it is important in some cases to use SUDO command, otherwise you will not be able to save your changes.

Answer (score 2):

Either do:

```
python3 -i pythonfile.py
```

At which you'll be entering the python editor after closing the program, or

Use a text editor like nano (since it's installed by default with most operating systems), or emacs, which also is a great terminal text editor.

```
nano pythonfile.py

emacs pythonfile.py -nw
```

(-nw is a non-gui mode)

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use an editor such as vi, vim or nano:

```
$ vi myFile.py
```