# how to open and edit py file in command prompt windows 10

Tags: python, command-prompt

I'm finding for a syntax equivalent to mac os terminal `open filename.py` in windows command prompt.
I've search internet to find answer like type in filename (or location) `filename.py` into command prompt, but that just run a script or even `start filename.py` doesn't seems to work too. how do i edit get to edit my code via command prompt?

Comment: go to a pyfile  .... and double click it ... whatever that does is what `start filename.py` will do... you can right click any py file and select open with, and choose your editor and make that the default behaviour ... then `start xxx.py` will open that ... alternatively you could type `pycharm file.py` or maybe `notepad++ file.py`  or something simillar

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to edit a py file from terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50419763/how-to-edit-a-py-file-from-terminal)

Comment: If you want to edit it then it will somewhat depend on which editor you want to use, then it depends if it's in PATH or if you want to write it out in full: `C:\path\to\editor\editor.exe filename.py` will probably work as expected. It could be as simple as `notepad filename.py` for something in your PATH. Beyond that, `START filename.py` will do whatever the double click action would be for that file extension. Which is probably to just run `python filename.py` and run the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to edit a file you can simply use `notepad`

```
notepad file.txt
```

you can install vim or nano and use them in windows

Comment: You could use WSL and install/use the nano editor in that? iirc it then becomes ẁsl nano filename.py`. Just be sure to do a linux-formatted filepath (e.g. / instead of \, / is root directory)

Answer (score 0):

If you have set the environment variable you can type

```
python fileName.py
```

Otherwise you will need to put the full path.In my case

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.7/ Python 3.7 (64-bit)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`open`](https://scriptingosx.com/2017/02/the-macos-open-command/) command in MacOS or even [`xdg-open`](https://manpage.me/?q=xdg%2Dopen) on Linux is for opening a file with its programs (associated by the operating-system depending on the file-type).

#### Windows command `start`

On Windows there is the [`start`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start) command:

> Starts a separate Command Prompt window to run a specified program or command.

#### Python equivalent to `start`

Also Python has [`os.startfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.startfile):

> Start a file with its associated application.

```py
import os
os.startfile("filename.py")
```

#### Manage Associations

The associated shell-execute command (associated default application and command to open the file) usually is stored and can be set in Windows-registry.

In the case of a `.py` file it can for example:

- open the file for editing using notepad
- execute the script via Python

On the Windows command-line `cmd.exe` you can use [`assoc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/assoc) and [`ftype`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ftype) to manage and alter the associations with a given file-type/-extension:

```
assoc /?
ftype /?
```

Note: on PowerShell prefix the commands with `cmd /c`

Use `assoc .py` to view the current file type association for Python scripts. If the resulting file-type name is `pyfile` then `ftype pyfile=%SystemRoot%\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE %1` binds the notepad (Windows default editor) as opening command/application.

#### See also

- Super User: [Linux equivalent command for "open" command on Mac/Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/38984/linux-equivalent-command-for-open-command-on-mac-windows)
- Microsoft Blog: [Setting default programs in Windows 10 via command line/Powershell](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e4a0438a-6ef6-4dd8-b9cd-776fe2ec4ba8/setting-default-programs-in-windows-10-via-command-linepowershell)
- Microsoft Docs: [Making file type associations enterprise ready](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/hewagen/making-file-type-associations-enterprise-ready)
- Microsoft Docs: [Windows 10 – How to configure file associations for IT Pros?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/windowsinternals/windows-10-how-to-configure-file-associations-for-it-pros)
- Microsoft Docs: [Launching Applications (ShellExecute, ShellExecuteEx, SHELLEXECUTEINFO) - Win32 apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/launch)